# Ratio of two tension forces in rods

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

> Suppose I am rotating a meter rod. At other end,there is an object of "m" kg.there is another rod connected with that object .This rod's length is also 1 meter .There is another object at the other end of the second rod .

what is the ratio of tension forces in these two rods when the objects are rotating with same angular velocity.

This question came in my exam at my school and answer is 2:3 but I think it should be 1:1.because first rod experiences one tension where the second rod experiences two tension forces.

Comment: In what dimension(s) is this rod being rotated? Perhaps providing a diagram would help enable better answers.

Comment: @AlexanderKalian horizontally .gravity is ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the tension in the rods are $T1$, and $T2$ respectively. The equation of force for the first object is:

$$ T1-T2= m\omega ^2 l$$

and for the second object:

$$ T2= m\omega ^2 2l$$

Divide both equations and you'll get your answer.